# Database is throwing exception while trying to store a file of size 2MB as a BLOB data

Tags: teradata

In one of my application i was trying to save one file (Size of the file is 2MB) in to the teradata database table as a BLOB data by using JDBC connection. But everytime i was getting one exception which is as follows

**com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.00.00.01] [Error 1186] [SQLState HY000] Parameter 2 length is 2215538 bytes, which is greater than the maximum 64000 bytes that can be set.**

Please help me out resolving this issue.

Thanks,
Sourav

Comment: What is the target table definition? Sounds like you are trying to put 10 lb of 'data' in a 5 lb 'bag'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the blob column larger ,or just use the system default value ,which is 2097088000 btw.

This is from Teradata User Documentations : SQL data types and literals Chapter 7
"the number of bytes to allocate for the BLOB column. The maximum number
of bytes is 2097088000, which is the default if n is not specified."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data in String format we can use setCharacterStream to bypass the restriction of 64000 bytes.

Using preparedStatement to insert large amount of data clob column as

```
pStmt.setCharacterStream(paramterIndex, new StringReader(StringToBeInserted), StringToBeInserted.length());
```