# R code to increase Teradata JDBC driver maximum byte length

Tags: r, jdbc, teradata, rjava, rjdbc

I'm trying to export some fairly large geometry objects into teradata from R, using bulk insert through RJDBC. The problem is some of the objects are over 64000 characters:

> Error in .jcall(ps, "V", "addBatch") :
>   java.sql.SQLException:
>   [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.00.00.28] [Error 1186] [SQLState
>   HY000] Parameter 2 length is 89190 bytes, which is greater than the
>   maximum 64000 bytes that can be set.

It looks like it's possible to increase this limit for CLOB columns, but I haven't been able to figure out R code to do that:

[Database is throwing exception while trying to store a file of size 2MB as a BLOB data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955723/database-is-throwing-exception-while-trying-to-store-a-file-of-size-2mb-as-a-blo)

And then here's my code for the insert:

```
myinsert <- function(...){
  kwargs <- list(...)
  for(i in seq_along(kwargs)) {
    .jcall(ps,"V","setString",as.integer(i), as.character(kwargs[i]))
  }
  .jcall(ps,"V","addBatch")
}
dbSendUpdate(conn, paste0("create table ", table_empty, "(SEA_ID INTEGER, poly SYSUDTLIB.ST_Geometry);"))
.jcall(conn@jc,"V","setAutoCommit",FALSE)
ps = .jcall(conn@jc,"Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;","prepareStatement", paste0("insert into ", table_empty, " values(?, ?)"))

for(n in 1:nrow(polys_td)){ 
  myinsert(polys_td$SEA_ID[[n]], polys_td$poly[[n]])
}
.jcall(ps,"[I","executeBatch")
```

Comment: What does you `myinsert` method do?

Comment: **Edit** your question, don't use comments for this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my bad, edited

Comment: I think you need to expand your `myinsert`, and modify it to wrap it in a `StringReader` and use `setCharacterStream` as suggested by the question you link.

Comment: BTW: Are there no libraries in R that do all this heavy work? Your JNI/reflection type access of the JDBC API seems rather painful.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel normally RJDBC can do most of this by itself, but sadly it's bugged for Teradata specifically, you are right - this is painful and suboptimal

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks, i will try to add StringReader

Comment: It might be worthwhile to first quickly test this in a Java program to see if it actually fixes the problem.